# Quickly setting up Kudu on IIS for Horizontal Scaling

Tags: iis, kudu

I have been playing around with Kudu on an IIS development server and succeeded in making it deploy a hello world site etc.

But I was wondering if there was some resources on how to deploy Kudu in larger environments. So that you can quickly add new server nodes (virtual) to balance load.

Is there some approach to manage multiple Kudu deployments from a centralized location? I know It has an REST API and obviously we can probably use this, but that sort of requires some development, so was just looking to see if there was an existing solution out there.

But So far I have either searched after the wrong thing on Google, or there isn't much of what I need.

Does anyone have any experience in running it in larger environments with many servers?